# Decompressing a BLOB from SQLite with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, compression, zlib

Using Python 2.7, I am storing web-pages in SQLite into a BLOB type column:

The compression is with zlib, and I'm inserting it as sqlite3.Binary type.

Without compression this works fine:

```
db_body = sqlite3.Binary(page_body)
dbc.execute("insert into table (content) values ?", db_body)
```

With compression also works fine:

```
db_body = sqlite3.Binary(zlib.compress(page_body))
dbc.execute("insert into table (content) values ?", db_body)
```

The problem comes when I try and retrieve the compressed data. I have tried the following:

```
dbc.execute("select content from table limit 1")
sql_result =  dbc.fetchone()

page_content = zlib.decompress(sql_result[0])
```

But the result (`page_content`) is a str type that's still compressed. There are no errors or exceptions. The content type of `sql_result[0]` is a [Buffer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#buffer), so the decompress function is changing the data type but not the content.

If I compress and recompress at the same time, without putting it through sqlite, the output is fine:

```
db_body = sqlite3.Binary(zlib.compress(page_body))
page_content = zlib.decompress(db_body)
```

So, how do I decompress data that I've inserted and then retrieved from SQLite?

Comment: how do you obtain squl_result ? Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you need to use `sqlite3.Binary`?

```
db = sqlite3.connect('/tmp/mydb')
db.execute('CREATE TABLE tbl (bin_clmn BLOB)')
db.execute('INSERT INTO tbl  VALUES(?)', [buffer(zlib.compress(page_body))])
db.commit()
db.close()


db = sqlite3.connect('/tmp/mydb')
row = db.execute('SELECT * FROM tbl').fetchone()
page_body_decompressed = zlib.decompress(str(row[0]))
print page_body == page_body_decompressed
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Seems like odd behaviour though; the sqlite3.Binary type is the one I read somewhere as being designed for storing binary data.